# pure-react-carousel dots I want to show the scrollbar which moves while my div slides

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to make a slider which I can achieve through pure-react-carousel but instead of dots I want to show the scrollbar which moves while my div slides. Please help me to achieve this

[image]

I want to achieve the scroll bar in between the prev and next button